# Why <space> is ignored after a block and esc-<space> is not?

Tags: spacing

My setup: web2cTeX (TeX Live).
Consider these two files, which are supposed to produce the same output.
--- file1.tex ---

```
\centerline{ab}\ %

cd
\bye
```

--- file2.tex ---

```
\centerline{ab} %

cd
\bye
```

Here is how 'dvitype' output for both files differ:

```
...
 [ab]
 134: pop 
 level 1:(h=0,v=655360,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=42) 
-135: y3 786432 v:=655360+786432=1441792, vv:=91 
-139: y0 786432 v:=1441792+786432=2228224, vv:=141 
-140: push 
-level 1:(h=0,v=2228224,w=0,x=0,y=786432,z=0,hh=0,vv=141) 
-141: right3 1310720 h:=0+1310720=1310720, hh:=83 
-145: setchar99 h:=1310720+291271=1601991, hh:=101 
-146: setchar100 h:=1601991+364090=1966081, hh:=124 
+135: down3 786432 v:=655360+786432=1441792, vv:=91 
+139: push 
+level 1:(h=0,v=1441792,w=0,x=0,y=0,z=0,hh=0,vv=91) 
+140: right3 1310720 h:=0+1310720=1310720, hh:=83 
+144: setchar99 h:=1310720+291271=1601991, hh:=101 
+145: setchar100 h:=1601991+364090=1966081, hh:=124 
 [ cd]
...
```

Both dvi files have the same size - 224 bytes.

AFAIK, space should not be ignored after a block, but apparently it is (in this specific case).
And I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two inputs are surely *not* supposed to produce the same result.

Since `\centerline{ab}` expands to `\hbox to \hsize{\hss #1\hss}` it doesn't take you out of vertical mode (after `ab` has been typeset in restricted horizontal mode).

The command `\⍽` (control space) is a horizontal command, so it starts a paragraph that's immediately ended by the blank line; the glue will be removed by `\par`.

So we have (finer details ignored)

```
<centered box with ab>
<parskip glue>
<indent box>
<parskip glue>
<indent box>cd
```

In the second example, the space token after `\centerline{ab}` appears in vertical mode, and space tokens in vertical mode are ignored. So we have

```
<centered box with ab>
<parskip glue>
<indent box>cd
```

because it's just the `c` that starts a paragraph.